# How to draw a soft line in gdi/gdi+

Tags: gdi+, gdi

soft line means, the line will draw some interim color around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GDI can't do this. For GDI+ see this Microsoft article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536351(VS.85).aspx

To turn on line smoothing use

```
myGraphics.SetSmoothingMode(SmoothingModeAntiAlias);
```

Comment: exactly what i'm looking for, thank you ! could you take a look at my another question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261536/how-to-let-gdi-gid-object-pen-brush-rect-region-etc-semi-transparent